# OSX Mail stuck in outbox

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I have multiple emails that are stuck in the outbox of my apple mail client for an IMAP account.

Mail connection doctor is reporting that connection and login to server succeeded.

I was able to send emails yesterday from a different location.

I have no idea how to diagnose this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!... Force stop and restart fixed it.